# Custom Post type & Taxonomy 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives, hierarchical

I've created a custom post type & taxonomy, however when I go to my taxonomy page it throws a 404 error and I can't understand why.

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function portfolio_post_type() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category','portfolio');
    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Portfolio'),
                'singular_name' => __('Portfolio'),
                'add_new' => __('Add new item'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add new item'),
                'edit' => __('Edit'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit item'),
                'new_item' => __('New item'),
                'view' => __('View item'),
                'view_item' => __('View item'),
                'search_items' => __('Search portfolio'),
                'not_found' => __('No portfolio items found'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No portfolio items found in trash'),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-art',
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions','author'),
            'can_export' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array('portfolio-category'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_post_type', 0 );

function portfolio_create_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'portfolio-category',
        'portfolio',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Category' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'category' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_create_taxonomy' );
```

When I click to view a taxonomy it takes me to `http://domain.local/category/all/`

However it throws the 404 page template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please replace the "portfolio_create_taxonomy" funcation to below code

```
function portfolio_create_taxonomy() {


    register_taxonomy(
        'portfolio-category',
        array( 'portfolio' ),

        array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
         'label' => __( 'Category' ),
         'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-category' ),
         'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_create_taxonomy' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Slug `category` is already in use. [Reserved_Terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms)

After making changes, open "Permalink Settings" page and click "Save".

```
function portfolio_post_type() {
    //register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category','portfolio');
    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Portfolio'),
                'singular_name' => __('Portfolio'),
                'add_new' => __('Add new item'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add new item'),
                'edit' => __('Edit'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit item'),
                'new_item' => __('New item'),
                'view' => __('View item'),
                'view_item' => __('View item'),
                'search_items' => __('Search portfolio'),
                'not_found' => __('No portfolio items found'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No portfolio items found in trash'),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-art',
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'revisions','author'),
            'can_export' => true,
            'taxonomies' => array('portfolio-category'),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_post_type');

function portfolio_create_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'portfolio-category',
        'portfolio',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Category' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-category' ), // changed from reserved "category" slug
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'portfolio_create_taxonomy' );
```